# Error en Tablas en HTML

Tags: html, css

tengo un problema con mi código y es que cuando hago una tabla al intentar seguir escribiendo abajo se sigue poniendo en la tabla y cuando pude cerrar la tabla el texto se ponía encima.

Aca el código

```html
    <tbody>
    <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="o">
    <tr bgcolor="gray">
    <td>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
    <tr bgcolor="green">
    
    
    <td width="10"><strong>Elemento</strong></td>
    <td width="300"><strong>Función</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="283">Header o Cabecera</td>
    <td width="283">El header o cabecera suele tener anchura completa. Es decir, que siempre ocupa el ancho completo de la pantalla en la cual se está visualizando. A excepción de las páginas web tipo box o caja. Por el contrario el contenido de la página no suele tener anchura completa, aunque puede haber algunos elementos en su interior que si la tengan.
    
    En el header o cabecera encontraremos varios elementos. Pero uno, fundamental, que es el menú de navegación de la web. A través de este elemento podremos acceder a todas las páginas del sitio web. </td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td width="283">Cuerpo</td>
    <td width="283">El cuerpo de la página está limitado en la parte superior con el header o cabecera  y en la parte inferior con el footer o pie.
    Cada página del sitio web tiene un contenido diferente. A diferencia del header y footer, cuyo contenido se repite en todas las páginas de la web.
    En el cuerpo se incluye el contenido específico de la página del sitio cuya url se muestra en la barra de direcciones del navegador.</td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td width="283">Pie o Footer</td>
    <td>El pie o footer es la parte inferior de una página web. Se sitúa bajo el cuerpo y su contenido se repite en todas las páginas del sitio web. Es decir, que todas las páginas de la web tienen el mismo footer o pie, salvo algunas excepciones como landing pages o páginas por el estilo donde específicamente se elimina el header y footer.</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Tienes una etiqueta <table> que no deberias tener el <tbody> va dentro de <table>. y no te recomiendo usar table, es mejor que te vas un video de css-grid que te toma unos 30 min y haces algo mejor... tu codigo no esta bien maquetado. deberias comenzarlo desde cero si quieres aprender bien.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes mal maquetada la tabla:

- La etiqueta `table` debe englobar al elemento `tbody` dado eso debes re acomodar este elemento
- Si vas a ocupar tbody entonces considera incluir thead para el área del encabezado
- En la medida de lo posible (aunque esto no afecta directamente) no coloques estilos a nivel de las etiquetas HTML
- Podemos eliminar el espacio entre las celdas con border-collapse

Puedes dejarlo así:

```html
    <style>
      table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse:collapse; 
      }
      .encabezado {
        background-color: green;
        color: white;
      }
      .cuerpo {
        background-color: gray;
      }
    </style>
    <table>
      <thead class="encabezado">
        <tr>
          <th>Elemento</th>
          <th>Función</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="cuerpo">
        <tr>
          <td>Elemento 1</td>
          <td>
            La descripción del elemento 1
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus facere minima, fugiat sint ipsa ducimus doloremque necessitatibus, enim nobis labore tempora ex porro qui cupiditate, quia? Ullam, consequatur laborum sapiente.
            </p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Elemento 2</td>
          <td>
            La descripción del elemento 2
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi repellat accusantium, nemo explicabo ad vel illo suscipit corrupti maiores asperiores impedit repudiandae aliquam, aspernatur, hic, doloremque accusamus tempore dolore minus.
            </p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>Hola Mundo</p>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, de lo del diseño, es por que esto es un trabajo escolar y no se mucho.

Comment: No hay de que @rapac56 y siempre eres bienvenido a preguntar

Comment: Y si quiero separar por líneas le quito el border collapse?

Comment: ¿Es decir que se vea la separación entre las celdas @rapac56?

Comment: si y cambiarlo de color

Comment: La opción mas rápida puede ser quitarle el collapse a la tabla y a esta misma dale un color de fondo con la propiedad de siempre de `background-color`

Comment: gracias, muy util